Is there a way to make a dictonary of mapped values?
My code is dramatically slowing down an optimization procedure. I am hoping it does not need to re-map every tuple per optimization step (200 tuples). Each time this function is called it does the remapping. I am hoping to define the mapping once, and per step only pull the values that the optimizer changed.
def get_weird_mapping(self,identification,tuple):
    delta_value = 0
    s1 = self.decode(tuple[0])
    s2 = self.decode(tuple[1])
    ident_list_forward = ['Intra -> S1', 'S1 -> S2', 'S2 -> S3', 'S3 -> S4', 'S4 -> S5', 'S5 -> S6', 'S6 -> Extra']
    if ((s1.count('1') or s2.count('1')) > 1) or ((s1.count('1') == 1 and s2.count('1')) == 2):
        delta_multiplicand = 1
        indices = [i for i, bit in enumerate(bin(int(s1, 2) & int(s2, 2))[2:].zfill(len(s1))) if bit == '1']
        transition_occupancy = [i for i, bit in enumerate(bin(int(s1, 2) ^ int(s2, 2))[2:].zfill(len(s1))) if
                                bit == '1']
        transition_occupancy_first = transition_occupancy[0]

        ident_prefix = bin(int(s1, 2) ^ int(s2, 2))[2:].zfill(len(s1)) + '_'
        for i in indices:
            delta_multiplicand = 1
            delta_prime = []
            delta_calc = []

            if i < transition_occupancy_first:
                delta_prime = [i - n for n in range(i + 1)]
                delta_calc = [ident_prefix + str(j + 1) for j in delta_prime]
            elif i > transition_occupancy_first:
                delta_prime = [i + n for n in range(6 - i)]
                delta_calc = [ident_prefix + str(j + 1) for j in delta_prime]

            if identification in ident_list_forward:
                for delta in delta_calc:
                    delta_multiplicand *= self.delta_dict.get(delta, 1)
            else:
                for delta in delta_calc:
                    ident_rev = delta + '_rev'
                    delta_multiplicand *= self.delta_dict.get(ident_rev, 1)

        delta_value += delta_multiplicand
    return delta_value

The function takes a tuple like (6,9), converts that to a binary code with s1 = binary_decoder(6) and s2 = binary_decoder(9) (represents numbers 000100 and 000101). I then use a bitwise & function to convert to an occupancy definition to return where 1's are in the same location (000100) and a bitwise XOR function to map where the difference is (000001).
It constructs a mapping starting place of 000001 then looks at the occupancy and applies a #! ending to the string, where the relationship is 000001_4 x 000001_3 x 000001_2 x 000001_1. 000001_# represents an optimizable parameter. For a XOR of 001100 and an occupancy at the 1st and 4th position it instead takes the factorial either backwards or forwards and adds the sums together. A tuple pair that converts to 011010 010110 becomes 001100_2x001100_1 + 001100_4x001100_5.
I am hoping to do all binary pairs once and generate a look-up table with this relationship as a function of tuple numbers as that relationship doesn't change with each step.

Write comments in your code for better understanding

please google your own question, and come back after. you're supposed to show some effort and you haven't reached the first step yet

Since you made multi-line codes into single-lines in many places, It is difficult to understand. For example, you could have split indices = [i for i, bit in enumerate(bin(int(s1, 2) & int(s2, 2))[2:].zfill(len(s1))) if bit == '1'] into multiple lines so that reading and understanding would be easier.
I assume that your problem occurs in mapping mutiple lines in the following lines:
s1 = self.decode(tuple[0])
s2 = self.decode(tuple[1])

When you have lot of elements in tuple and you want to map within the elements in a single function, you can follow this technique. Create a dict and make your variables as keys of the dict and expressions as the values of the dict. if the variable needs to be called call using dict[key].
dct_1 = {}  

for i in range(len(tuple)):
    dct_1[f's{i + 1}'] = self.decode(tuple[i])

If at all you want to call the variable in later step, for example if you want to print the variable s5:
print(dct_1['s5'])

If further mapping is required from the same dict,Use the same technique.  create another dict say dct_2 and use the keys and values of dct_1 in dct_2 and map new key, value pair in dct_2.

I eventually just restructured the way it was handling things by separating the two functions. The first one, gen_delta_transitions handled the mapping portion of it, mapping a tuple to a nested list that contained the string names of N! values that I needed for each unique s1 and s2 value. It did this at initialization. Then the second function was written to reference this mapping and pull a value from a separate dictionary I had created to map a name to a value that the optimizer changes.
    def gen_delta_transitions(self):
        mapping = dict()
        for j in range(self.N_coeffs):
            for tuple in self.transitions[j]:
                delta_calc = [[]]
                s1 = self.decode(tuple[0])
                s2 = self.decode(tuple[1])
                if ((s1.count('1') or s2.count('1')) > 1) or ((s1.count('1') == 1 and s2.count('1')) == 2):
                    indices = [i for i, bit in enumerate(bin(int(s1, 2) & int(s2, 2))[2:].zfill(len(s1))) if bit == '1']
                    transition_occupancy = [i for i, bit in enumerate(bin(int(s1, 2) ^ int(s2, 2))[2:].zfill(len(s1)))
                                            if
                                            bit == '1']
                    ident_prefix = bin(int(s1, 2) ^ int(s2, 2))[2:].zfill(len(s1)) + '_'
                    for i in indices:
                        if i < transition_occupancy[0]:
                            delta_prime = [i - n for n in range(i + 1)]
                            occupancy = [ident_prefix + str(j + 1) for j in delta_prime]
                            delta_calc[0].append(occupancy)
                        elif i > transition_occupancy[0]:
                            delta_prime = [i + n for n in range(6 - i)]
                            occupancy = [ident_prefix + str(j + 1) for j in delta_prime]
                            delta_calc[0].append(occupancy)
                    mapping[tuple] = delta_calc
        return mapping

    def get_electrostatics(self,identification,tuple):
        delta_value = 0
        ident_list_forward = ['Intra -> S1', 'S1 -> S2', 'S2 -> S3', 'S3 -> S4', 'S4 -> S5', 'S5 -> S6', 'S6 -> Extra']
        if tuple in self.delta_mapping:
            delta_calc = self.delta_mapping[tuple]
            for i in delta_calc:
                for j in i:
                    delta_multiplicand = 1
                    if identification in ident_list_forward:
                        for value in j:
                            delta_multiplicand *= self.delta_dict.get(value,1)
                    else:
                        for value in j:
                            new_ident = value + '_rev'
                            delta_multiplicand *= self.delta_dict.get(new_ident,1)
                    delta_value += delta_multiplicand
        return delta_value

